# ambiguous overload for 'operator >>' cpp

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, dev-c++, ambiguous

I'm using devC++ and don't know what's the problem.
when I try to execute the following code it creates this error

> ambiguous overload for operator >> (operands types are
>   std::istream{aka std::basic stream} and int)

some screen shots are also attached.[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVlmw.jpg)
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AFDY.jpg)

```
   #include<iostream>
   #include<conio.h>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
      int n;
      cin >> n;

      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: In your screen shot but not in your written code, get rid of the `#include <conio.h>` since it's not needed.

Comment: even after removing it, error still remains.

Comment: I had the same error before, I reinstalled the DevC++, It worked fine for couple of months but now the same problem.

Comment: Which version of dev c++ are you using?

Comment: DevC++ version 5.11

Comment: Very strange. The only guess I can make is that `<iostream>` is including another header file, and something has gone wrong in your environment to mean that other header file is not getting included properly.

Comment: I agree with @John. It compiles and runs fine on [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/fQvxPb) as it should. (ideone states to use `gcc 6.3`.)